# How to maintain separate sessions for Remote applications launched from same pc with same credentials

Tags: remoteapp

I am Launching 2 different remote apps on a pc , 1 Unified session id is assigned for both the applications (both remote apps are part of 1 RDP session). How can we have separate session id's assigned for each remote app?

Or is there any way to get the sessions per remote app?

I am using win 12 r2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution 
There is a setting disableconnectionsharing:i:1  which you have to add in RDP file.

for more details refer http://www.donkz.nl/files/rdpsettings.html

Was disappointing that i did not receive reply from stack overflow and even msdn. Any ways found a answer..